# Type constraints on typeclass instances in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-constraints

So I was playing around with [Data.Set.Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/set-monad-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Set-Monad.html), which does not seem to be an instance of [Data.Foldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Foldable.html) like [Data.Set](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Set.html) is. I decided to try and add this instance myself as an experiment:

```hs
import Data.Foldable (Foldable, foldr)
import qualified Data.Set.Monad as S (Set, foldr)

instance Foldable S.Set where
  foldr = S.foldr
```

I get compilation error:

```hs
No instance for (Ord a) arising from a use of ‘S.foldr’
Possible fix:
  add (Ord a) to the context of
    the type signature for foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Set a -> b
In the expression: S.foldr
In an equation for ‘foldr’: foldr = S.foldr
In the instance declaration for ‘Foldable Set’
```

Okay, this must be because `S.foldr :: Ord a => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Set a -> b`. How do I express this constraint in the instance declaration? I tried this:

```hs
instance (Ord a) => Foldable (Set a) where
  foldr = S.foldr
```

And get another compilation error:

```hs
The first argument of ‘Foldable’ should have kind ‘* -> *’,
  but ‘Set a’ has kind ‘*’
In the instance declaration for ‘Foldable (Set a)’
```

What am I doing wrong? Or will Haskell even let me create this instance at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, you need to define `Foldable Set`. Which means you can't depend on `a`, since `foldr` is required to work for *any* `a`.

So basically you would need constraint kinds to be embedded into the definition of `Foldable` to make this work, I think.

Note that `Data.Set.foldr` doesn't have the `Ord a` constraint so it can define a `Foldable` instance.

Comment: I think I understand. In short, it's not possible to create that instance?

Comment: @arussell84 Correct, unless you can write a fold that doesn't require `Ord a`. I don't trust their api, they have `Ord a` requirements in places that should not require it.